# Is there a way to dynamically insert click events in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lifecycle

Trying to achieve inserting some computed methods onto an element depending on mobile viewports only. Here's a basic gist of what I'm working with:

```
<a class="nav-link float-left p-x-y-16" v-bind:class={active:isCurrentTopicId(t.id)} @click="onTopicClicked($event, m, t)" href="#">{{t.title}}</a>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isClosed: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        toggleMenu() {
            return {
                isClosed: this.isClosed
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        browserWidth(prevWidth, newWidth) {
            console.log('width changed from ' + newWidth + ' to ' + prevWidth);
    },
    mounted() {
        var that = this;
        this.$nextTick(function() {
            window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
                that.browserWidth = window.innerWidth;
                if(that.browserWidth > 824) {
                    console.log('Desktop View');
                } else {
                    console.log('Mobile View');
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

I would like to try to use the resize event to determine browser width so that I can dynamically insert the computed function onto that `<a>` tag

Comment: What's your goal, but purely functional perspective?

Comment: I just want it to work lol. It seems like a simple enough thing to do where it shouldn't affect the entire project drastically performance wise. All it's really doing is toggling some CSS. It works when I have
@click="onTopicClicked($event, m, t); isClosed = !isClosed". I'd like to achieve the same thing but instead of already declaring the event there - I'd like to dynamically insert it on mobile views.

Comment: declare one data property like `customEvent: function () {}` and in the template, `<a @click="customEvent()" />`, then if some event triggered, assign `customEvent=function (data, m, t) {/*do something*/}`

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either provide two different elements (one for desktop and another for mobile) as stated by Karthikeyan, or conditionally add click event to that element:

```
v-on="isMobileView ? { mouseover: onTopicClicked($event, m, t) } : {}"
```

Comment: I like this one @Nimaj suggested than my solution, as here the html code is not duplicated

Comment: I added these two methods for the sake of testing what is firing
`enabled() {console.log('enabled')}, disabled() {console.log('disabled')}` and on the element it looks like `v-on:click="isDesktopView ? {click: disabled()} : {click: enabled()}"` but it seems to only log "disabled" whether I'm desktop or mobile.

Comment: I use Vue3, If event handler with brackets, like this, `<canvas id="s-canvas" :width="contentWidth" :height="contentHeight" v-on="refreshByClick?{click:refreshCode()}:{}"></canvas>`. It seems doesn't work and component doesn't render, but if without brackets, It works fine. I don't know why this happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a data that says if the view is mobile or not and use v-if , v-else and have the @click only added to the v-if="isMobileView"

```
<a v-if="isMobileView" class="nav-link float-left p-x-y-16" v-bind:class={active:isCurrentTopicId(t.id)} @click="onTopicClicked($event, m, t)" href="#">{{t.title}}</a>

<a v-else class="nav-link float-left p-x-y-16" v-bind:class={active:isCurrentTopicId(t.id)} href="#">{{t.title}}</a>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isClosed: false,
            isMobileView: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        toggleMenu() {
            return {
                isClosed: this.isClosed
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        browserWidth(prevWidth, newWidth) {
            console.log('width changed from ' + newWidth + ' to ' + prevWidth);
    },
    mounted() {
        var that = this;
        function checkIfMobileView() {
            that.isMobileView = window.innerWidth <= 824;
        }
        this.$nextTick(function() {
            window.addEventListener('resize', checkIfMobileView);
        });
        checkIfMobileView();
    }
}
</script>
```